# Select string that contains square 2

Tags: sql-server

I want to select rows that contain square 2 (this char '²')

I did `select myColumn from table where myColumn '%²%'` 
I got the columns that contain '²' but also the ones that contain '2'.

I tried `select myColumn from table where myColumn '%2%'` and I got the same result.

Is there a way in SQL Server to select the column that only contains the square 2 char?

Comment: `²` is a different *single Unicode* character than `2`. It's not 2 with some modifier. The *collation* though may consider them equivalent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use proper collation, like `Latin1_General_BIN` for example.

```
declare @t table(t nvarchar(20))
insert into @t values('²'), ('2')
-- Will return only the row with the number.
select * from @t where t like N'%2%' collate Latin1_General_BIN
-- Will return only the row with square 2.
select * from @t where t like N'%²%' collate Latin1_General_BIN
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that SQL Server treats `'2'` and `'²'` as the same character in a case insensitive collation (maybe `'²'` is a lower case `'2'` in SQL Server's eyes?). If you run the following, for example:

```
SELECT CASE N'²' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS WHEN N'2' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Sensitive,
       CASE N'²' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI WHEN N'2' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CaseSensitive,
       CASE N'²' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS WHEN N'2' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AccentSensitive,
       CASE N'²' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI WHEN N'2' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Insensitive;
```

The output is:

```
Sensitive CaseSensitive AccentSensitive Insensitive
------------ ------------- --------------- -----------
0            0             1               1
```

You'll need to use a Case Sensitive collation if you want `'2'` and `'²'` to be treated differently.